# How to redirect root to directory under root with .htaccess?

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, redirect

If I install a cms at the root of my domain, and use URL rewriting to get clean URLs, I can no longer host files in arbitrary directories under the root. (Files that aren't suitable for the cms to handle.) So I am looking for a way to achieve the following:

- install the cms in a subdirectory, rather than root, e.g. *mydomain.com/cms/*
- when a browser visits mydomain.com, it should be redirected to *mydomain.com/cms/* to see the main page of the site.
- when a browser visits *mydomain.com/some-other-folder*, it should be able to access files there in a standard way, without interference from the cms.

I tried the simple-minded solution of

```
Redirect / /cms
```

but this only creates an infinite loop. What are my other options, please?

Answer (score 3):

[Looks like ServerFault already had the answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/9992/how-to-get-apache2-to-redirect-to-a-subdirectory) which I missed, since the .htacces tag wasn't used:

```
RedirectMatch ^/$ /cms/
```

seems to do what I need.

I would still appreciate comments if this is the right thing to do or if there are any side issues to be aware of.

Comment: I'd say this is the right thing to do.