# Apache : Map one virtualhost to a subdirectory of another virtualhost

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy, reverse-proxy, django

I'm trying to map one virtual host to a subdirectory of another virtual host, something like this `http://host2.com -> http://host1.com/host2`. At this moment, whenever I go to http://host2.com it maps to http://host1.com instead of http://host1.com/host2

My default site file is this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName "host1.com"

 <Directory /srv/www/host1>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
 </Directory>

 DocumentRoot /srv/www/host1
 WSGIScriptAlias / /srv/www/host1/apache/django.wsgi

 </VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName "host2.com"
    DocumentRoot /srv/www/host1

    <Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    ProxyPass / http://host1.com/host2
    ProxyPassReverse / http://host1.com/host2

</VirtualHost>
```

What am I missing? I'm not sure if it should matter, but I'm using Django with wsgi.

Answer (score 3):

This can actually be accomplished using a single `<VirualHost />`, by using the `ServerAlias` directive.  You can then use the `RewriteRule` to pass those requests to the proper directory, and by leaving off `[R]` you will just be rewriting the request, leaving the URL intact.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName host1.com
    ServerAlias host2.com

    <Directory /srv/www/host1>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    DocumentRoot /srv/www/host1
    WSGIScriptAlias / /srv/www/host1/apache/django.wsgi

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} host2\.com [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*) /host2$1 [L]
</VirtualHost>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another post that might help:
[Redir](https://serverfault.com/questions/9992/how-to-get-apache2-to-redirect-to-a-subdirectory)

I haven't tested this below but you get the idea.

You could use redirecting:

`RewriteEngine On`

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.host2\.com [NC]`

`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://host1\.com\host2 [L,R=301]`

Comment: hmmm. I was hoping reverse proxy would do it for me.

Comment: And in your solution the users will see new url, ie http://host1.com/host2. I want this part to be behind the scenes, the user should see only http://host.com

Comment: Ahh, I see. The only way I've preserved the URL in the browser Address Bar in the past is using a single pixel `.gif` image and a META REFRESH in HTML.