# Serve PHP page mapped as part of Django's (Python's) virtualhost

Tags: apache-2.2, php, virtualhost, django, wsgi

I have a question similar to this: [Apache : Map one virtualhost to a subdirectory of another virtualhost](https://serverfault.com/questions/253565/apache-map-one-virtualhost-to-a-subdirectory-of-another-virtualhost)

Except mine is about serving PHP within Django's domain like that:

- `example.com` serves Django, uses WSGI etc.,
- `example.com/some_app` needs to be fully based on PHP, cannot go through Django,

How can I do that? I believe this is possible, but could you give me any clues about how to accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Alias directory takes precdence over WSGIScriptAlias, so define Alias directive for /some_app to directory which is setup with PHP files.