# Rewriting main domain to subdomain (mod_rewrite)

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So I'm trying to write a mod_rewrite rule that will send everything on my main domain to a subdomain.

For example, redirect

```
http://example.com/1/2/3/4/5?n=6&i=7
```

to

```
http://sub.example.com/1/2/3/4/5?n=6&i=7
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond ^http://www\.example.com\/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://sub.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But it doesn't seem to working. Any tips?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Everything You Ever Wanted to Know about Mod_Rewrite Rules but Were Afraid to Ask?](http://serverfault.com/questions/214512/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-mod-rewrite-rules-but-were-afraid-to-ask)

Comment: @Shane Madden - don't think it's a dupe myself. That linked q is very helpful, but since it doesn't cover this specific question I think it is useful in its own right.

Comment: @Gavin Fair point.  That question could use a wider breadth of examples, it's a little heavy on referrer examples at the moment.

Comment: Try adding the following to `.htaccess` in the parent directory above the directory of interest: `RedirectMatch ^/foo/$ /foo/bar/` or `RedirectMatch ^/foo/$ /bar/baz/`. Also see [How to get apache2 to redirect to a subdirectory](http://serverfault.com/q/9992/145545).

Answer (score 3):

I think you're missing something in your RewriteCond line. Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^http://www\.example.com\/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://sub.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

So add the `%{HTTP_HOST}` into your RewriteCond rule... Note that I haven't tested this, so please post the results...

Comment: Doesn't the dot for `.com` in the RewriteCond need escaping?

Comment: In its current state this won't do anything. The `HTTP_HOST` server variable contains just the _hostname_ (whatever is in the `Host` HTTP request header) - it does not contain the protocol (`http://`), or part of the URL-path (the trailing slash in the above example). The OP also uses the domain apex in the example URL, whereas this specifically checks for the www subdomain. And yes, the second dot before the TLD does ideally need escaping (although unlikely to cause a problem if not). So, the condition should be written like: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com [NC]`